# How to call MySQL stored procedure with multiple input values from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, stored-procedures

This is my MySQL stored procedure.

```
    create procedure InsertIntotblStudentProc (PStudentId VARCHAR(10), PStudentName VARCHAR(10))
    begin
    insert into tblStudent (StudentId, StudentName) values (PStudentId, PStudentName);
end;
```

Here's my ASP code.

```
   `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("InsertIntotblStudent", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PStudentId", TextBox1.Text);`
```

I stopped here as I want to call procedure with two parameters and my other parameter is in TextBox2.

Help me with suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add mutiple parameters in command.Parameters, refer the below code for the same.

```
        var connectionString = ""; // Provide connecction string here.
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("InsertIntotblStudent", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("PStudentId", TextBox1.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("PStudentName", TextBox2.Text));
        command.Connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Connection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using list of `MySqlParameter` like this:

```
    var sqlParameters = new List<MySqlParameter>();
    sqlParameters.Add(new MySqlParameter { MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32, ParameterName = "@valuename", Value = textbox1 });
        .
        .
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters.ToArray());
```